# Reading a String value from CSV Sheet

Tags: python, psse

I am receiving an integer error when reading from my CSV sheet. Its giving me problems reading the last column. I know theres characters in the last column but how do I define `digit` as a character. The API function `psspy.two_winding_chg_4` requires an input using single quotes ' ' as shown below in that function(3rd element of the array)[image: excel sheet]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\win4.py", line 133, in <module>
psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%s'%digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
File ".\psspy.py", line 25578, in two_winding_chng_4
TypeError: an integer is required
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T1'

for row in data:
    data_location, year_link, from_, to, min_value,max_value,name2,tla_2,digit = row[5:14]
    output = 'From Bus #: {}\tTo Bus #: {}\tVMAX: {} pu\tVMIN: {} pu\t'
    if year_link == year and data_location == location and tla_2==location:
       from_=int(from_)
       to=int(to)
       min_value=float(min_value)
       max_value=float(max_value)
       digit=int(digit)
       print(output.format(from_, to, max_value, min_value))
      _i=psspy.getdefaultint()
      _f=psspy.getdefaultreal()
       psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%s'%digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
```

Comment: maybe you could print your arguments before calling the function. I wonder where this non-number comes from.

Comment: is `'%s' %digit` the correct way of storing string value into single quote

Comment: nope. You need `"'{}'".format(digit)`